# Permutations and sign flips isomorphic to S4?

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory

Let's start with a three-parameter set $\{a,b,c\}$. Consider i) all possible permutations of the set, ii) all possible sign flips of a pair of parameters.

Is it true that i) and ii) with the identity element form a group that is isomorphic to the symmetric group $S_4$? If yes, how to prove it?

Comment: How do you flip the "sign" of zero?

Comment: Sorry, I should not have written {0,1,2} but {a,b,c} instead. I edited it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is true.

It is well known that $S_4$ is isomorphic to the group of rotation symmetries of the cube. This is because a cube rotation is uniquely determined by the permutation of the four body diagonals.

You can also consider the three axes of the cube (connecting opposite face centres). Any rotation of the cube is a permutation of the three axes, possibly combined with a sign flip of two axes which is a 180 degree rotation about the other axis.